# SQL Count from table and display individual counts in while display php

Tags: php, sql, count

Hi I am fairly new to databases, and I am trying to count data from a db that has related tables. I am trying to count an entry that is related to record in another table, and then display that count next to the related record. At the moment I am just getting the full count of the entries, and displaying the full count next to all the records.![enter image description here][1]

```
//Individual Stores Total
$query_stores = "SELECT COUNT(stores.name) AS num FROM entries,stores WHERE stores.id = entries.store_id AND valid=1";
$results_stores = mysql_query($query_stores);
$rows_stores = mysql_fetch_array($results_stores);


echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td >" . $info['name'] . "</td>";  
      echo "<td>" . $info['code'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td bgcolor='#00B050'>" . $rows_stores['num'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(stores.id) AS num, stores.name, stores.id as code
FROM entries,stores 
WHERE stores.id = entries.store_id AND valid=1
GROUP BY stores.id
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestions... I have tried all your suggestions. @RainHeart > I have tried you query, and it seemed to give the best response, although It is still populating the whole array with the count instead of just the feilds that are related with the data. Do you have any other tips I can try?

Comment: I don't understand `It is still populating the whole array with the count instead of just the fields that are related with the data`. Please, tell me what you get with the query and what you want to get (in the first message) and we'll be able to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong. Try something like this:

```
SELECT e.id, count(s.name) FROM entries as e JOIN stores as s ON (e.store_id=s.id)
      WHERE e.valid=true
      GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: The query is fine. I tested mysql workbench before implementing in the code. I just dont know how to display the data as desired

Answer (score 0):

You have to join both the tables and use group by

```
$query_stores = "SELECT COUNT(stores.name) AS num FROM entries Inner Join stores ON   
                 stores.id = entries.store_id WHERE valid=1 GROUP BY stores.name";
$results_stores = mysql_query($query_stores);
$rows_stores = mysql_fetch_array($results_stores);
```

Comment: > I have tried to join the tables, but upon using the while condition to populate the data, the display will be the full number of count in the column, and not the individual related entires. See also RainHearts query...